# Bfs modification to find compatible paths in a directed graph

Tags: python, algorithm, graph-theory, breadth-first-search

I have the following directed graph and every node has one or more attributes. I try to modify bfs algorithm to find all possible paths from a starting node until the given attributes are covered. I also want the path that i found to not be a part of a cycle. [image]

For this graph if i start from node 1 and i want to cover attr 4 the paths that my algorithm will find are:

```
1-2-3
1-2-5-3
1-2-5-6-8
```

If i add the edge `3-1` then the paths `1-2-3` and `1-2-5-3` i want not to be accepted because are part of a cycle. So in my algorithm i try to check the neighbors of the last visited node and if the neighbor has already visited then i try to discard this path but my algorithm doesnt work in this case. If i add the edge `3-1` it returns the same paths. How can i fix this?
Here is my code:

```
G = nx.DiGraph()

G.add_edge(1,2)
G.add_edge(2,3)
G.add_edge(2,5)
G.add_edge(3,4)
G.add_edge(5,3)
G.add_edge(5,6)
G.add_edge(5,7)
G.add_edge(6,8)
G.add_edge(3,1)

def checkIfRequiredAttrsAreCovered(path, attrsToBeCovered):
    coveredAttrs = []
    counter = 0
    for node in path:
        coveredAttrs.extend(G.node[node]['attrs'])
    for i in attrsToBeCovered:
        if i in coveredAttrs:
            counter = counter + 1
    if counter == len(attrsToBeCovered):
        return True
    else:
        return False


def bfs(G, startingNode, attrsToBeCovered):
    paths = []
    q = queue.Queue()
    q.put([startingNode])
    while not q.empty():
        v = q.get()
        if checkIfRequiredAttrsAreCovered(v, attrsToBeCovered) == True:
            for i in G.neighbors(v[-1]):
                if i in v:
                    break
            paths.append(v) #print(v)
        else:
            for node in G.neighbors(v[-1]):
                if node not in v:
                    path = []
                    path.extend(v)
                    path.append(node)
                    q.put(path)

    print(paths)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume that you don't care if nodes are part of a bigger cycle. E.g. if 4 is connected to 1 and 3 is in a cycle 1-2-3-4. If you want to handle this, you may start a dfs from each matching node, with the current path set as visited.

First, [you should use snake case in Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Second, you should use `set`s to compare the attributes covered to the attributes to be covered. For a path, compute the set of covered attributes and compare the sets:

```
def check_if_required_attrs_are_covered(G, path, attrs_to_be_covered): # be sure to pass G as an argument here
    covered_attrs = set([G.node[n]['attrs'] for n in path])
    return covered_attrs >= attrs_to_be_covered
```

Third, some remarks on the `bfs` function:

- A test `if b == True:` is equivalent to `if b:`, because for a boolean `b == (b == True)` (try with True and False to convince yourself)
- The way you append a path to `q` may be shortened to `q.put(v+ [node])`
- You probably do not need a synchonized `queue`: use a list
- Use return instead of print or even better, create a generator that yields paths when they are found.

Four: what is the problem? Look at the `for i in G.neighbors(v[-1]):` loop. 
Whether you `break` or not, you go to the line `paths.append(v)`. 
That's why you do not exclude the paths with cycles. You want to distinguish the normal end of the loop from the break. 
That's a perfect case for confidential loop syntax in Python: the [`for...else` loop](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops).
I quote the doc: "a loop’s else clause runs when no `break` occurs". This gives the following code:

```
for i in G.neighbors(v[-1]):
    if i in v:
        break
else: # no neighbor from v[-1] in v
    yield v # instead of paths.append(v)
```

But you can also use `any` for a more natural expression:

```
if not any(i in v for i in G.neighbors(v[-1])):
    yield v # instead of paths.append(v)
```

This gives the following code:

```
def bfs(G, starting_node, attrs_to_be_covered):
    q = [[starting_node]]
    while q:
        v = q.pop()
        if check_if_required_attrs_are_covered(G, v, attrs_to_be_covered): # be sure to pass G as an argument
            if not any(i in v for i in G.neighbors(v[-1])):
                yield v
        else:
            for node in G.neighbors(v[-1]):
                if node not in v:
                    q.append(v+ [node])
```

Try it with:

```
print (list(bfs(G, 1,  set(["attr4"]))))
```